# Determine which .jar files are used

Tags: java, jar

I have a program that will not compile due to certain libraries not being found. I have tried using the -cp %pathTo\lib%/* command to include all .jar files. That gets it to compile but then when I try to run the program it tells me it cannot find or load the main class.

So I want to manually include each .jar file, my only problem is I don't know which exact ones to include.

```
/* ---------------------
 * ThermometerDemo1.java
 * ---------------------
 * (C) Copyright 2002-2007, by Object Refinery Limited.
 *
 */


import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ThermometerPlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultValueDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.ValueDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;

/**
 * A simple demonstration application showing how to create a thermometer.
 */
public class ThermDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

static class ContentPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

    JSlider slider;

    DefaultValueDataset dataset;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public ContentPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
        this.slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        this.slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        this.slider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
        this.slider.addChangeListener(this);
        add(this.slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(this.slider.getValue());
        add(new ChartPanel(createChart(this.dataset)));
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(ValueDataset dataset) {
        ThermometerPlot plot = new ThermometerPlot(dataset);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
            "Thermometer Demo 1",  // chart title
            JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,
            plot,                  // plot
            true                  // no legend
        );               

        plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        plot.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0));
        plot.setThermometerStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
        plot.setThermometerPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setUnits(ThermometerPlot.UNITS_FAHRENHEIT);
        plot.setGap(3);
        return chart;       
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        this.dataset.setValue(new Integer(this.slider.getValue()));
    }

}

/**
 * Creates a new demo.
 *
 * @param title  the frame title.
 */
public ThermDemo(String title) {
    super(title);
    JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

/**
 * Creates a panel for the demo (used by SuperDemo.java).
 * 
 * @return A panel.
 */
public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    return new ContentPanel();
}

/**
 * Starting point for the demonstration application.
 *
 * @param args  ignored.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThermDemo demo = new ThermDemo("Thermometer Demo 1");
    demo.pack();
    demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Commands:

to compile:
 javac -cp B:\Programming\Java\Compiler\lib* ThermDemo.java

to run: java ThermDemo

After compiling there are two new files in my current directory.
ThermDemo$ContentPanel.class, and ThermDemo.class

Comment: Show us the exact command you are running, and also please include code from the class which contains the `main()` method you want to use as an entry point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to compile: javac -cp B:\Programming\Java\Compiler\lib* ThermDemo.java
>
> to run: java ThermDemo

Change that to:

```
java -cp .;B:\Programming\Java\Compiler\lib* ThermDemo
```

The runtime classpath needs to include (at least) all of the compile-time dependencies.  The ".;" is needed to tell `java` to look in the current directory as well ... to find the ".class" files you just compiled.

Actually, this solution only applies to your current problem.   There is a lot of complexity in the way that classpaths work, and you would be advised to spend time reading up on it.  Here's a good place to start:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

---

(I'm assuming that `ThermoDemo.java` has a `main` method with the appropriate signature.)

Comment: Thank you so much!


Why do I need to re-include the path to the .jar files?


And also is the .; command used because there is another .class file apart from the main one that is compiled?

Comment: Why?  Because that is the way it works!  The compile-time classpath is not recorded in anything that the compiler emits.

Answer (score 0):

`ThermDemo.class` is the class that you have to run. `ThermDemo$ContentPanel.class` is the inner class. When you compile a class having inner classes, both class files will be generated.